# Writing a file to another file

Tags: java, file, filewriter

When I tried to run `OUT.TXT` it was alwasy empty.  Can you please assist me in finding out why?  Also `SPY.LOG` lines are not ordinary, can you assit with a way to fix those lines also?

```
package burak;
import java.io.*;

public class Yucal {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String fileName = "spy.log";
        String line;
        try {

            FileReader fileReader =  new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
            try{
                  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
                  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                  out.write(line);
                  out.close();
                  }
            catch (Exception e){
                  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  }
            System.out.printf("%65s\n", line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");           }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you yelling? :(

Comment: Don't shout at me; I'm a little sensitive, so here I go without answering you.

Comment: what do you mean 'not ordinary'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few changes

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    try {
        out.write(line);
        out.write("\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.printf("%65s\n", line);
}
out.close();
bufferedReader.close();
```

The mistake was you've opened `FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");` within while loop. It must be outside.

Answer (score 1):

```
        FileReader fileReader =  new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
        try{
              >FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");**
              >BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);**

        <snip>
```

Everytime you  open your file and write one line. Then close it. Next time you open it, you overwrite the previous contents of the file. You should probably move the lines marked with **>** outside the while loop.

The last line of your file **spy.log** might be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally move all close statements to finally block.

You might also need to handler some IO exceptions when you close these streams.

Hope this helps.